# Different answers to this probability problem

Tags: probability

> The Grunters and the Screamers are playing for the Grand Championship, which is a best of 7 series. The first team to win 4 games wins the Championship. Each team has a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of winning any individual game. What is the probability that the Grunters win in exactly 6 games?

If I solve this question using binomial probability, I get:

$\binom{5}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ $=$ $\frac{5}{32}$

---

However, if I try solving it as $\frac{\text{# ways for Grunters to win in 6 games}}{\text{# total outcomes in 4, 5, 6, 7 games}}$ I get $\frac{\binom{5}{3}}{2 \binom{3}{3} + 2 \binom{4}{3}+2 \binom{5}{3}+2 \binom{6}{3}}$ $=$ $\frac{1}{7}$.

Why don't these two answers match up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is correct. The events in the second denominator are of differing probabilities because of different numbers of games, so you can't add them.

Comment: But aren't you counting the number of ways in the denominator, not the probability?

Comment: GGGG, with G winning in four games, covers eight possibilities, all extensions to seven games

Comment: How does it cover eight possibilities?

Comment: Your total outcomes are all the $2^7$ series of results.  The two sweeps cover $16$ of these, as they ignore the results of the last three games.  Think of the chance to get four tails in a row flipping a coin.  Clearly that is $\frac 1{16}$, but you could think of $\frac {\text{1 way to get four tails}}{H+TH+TTH+TTTH+TTTT}=\frac 15$.  This fails for the same reason-$H$ covers $HTTT, HTTH$ and others.

Comment: I think Ross is including games 5, 6 and 7 and there are 8 possibilities. However since the series ends after either side wins 4 games, I'm not sure why we need to include the extensions to 7 games...

Comment: @undergrad:  that is correct.  Considering extensions to 7 games makes all the series have the same probability.

Comment: @Ross I think I understand your point. We can't add the number of ways in which the series ends in 4, 5, 6 or 7 games because the probability that the series ends in 4 games is different than the probability that the series ends in 5, 6 or 7 games. Subtle but important point.